# Simple ODE Analytical Solution Question: $\frac{dx}{dt} = ax + bu$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

my question is in regards to the following formula:

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}=ax+bu
\end{align}

where **x(0)=0** & **u=constant** and **a & b are scalar**

The answer to this or at least what I was given as the answer is the following:

\begin{align}
x=-\frac{bu}{a}(1-e^{at)}
\end{align}

Now I understand that I need to manipulate the formula and integrate both sides. Utilizing the integration table I perform the following:

Since **u=constant** we can then say **bu=b** therefore:

\begin{align}
\frac {dx}{ax+b}= {dt}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\int \frac {dx}{ax+b}= \int{dt}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a}ln|ax+b| = t + C
\end{align}

\begin{align}
e^{ln|ax+b|} = e^{(t + C)a}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
ax+b = e^{at+Ct}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
x = -\frac{b}{a} \frac{e^{at}e^{Ct}}{a}
\end{align}

I do not see where I am going wrong in the calcs above. I would appreciate any help in identifying where I went wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Actually you should have $ax+b=\pm e^{a(t+C)}$ after you remove the absolute value signs. (Unless it's given that $b>0$.) Then with $x(0)=0$ you get $b=\pm e^{aC}$. I would recommend solving such an equation using the method of integrating factor instead, then there are no pitfalls like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reached upto

$$ax+B = e^{at+\color{red}{Ca}} \implies ax=e^{(t+C)a}-B \implies x=\frac{1}{a}\left(e^{(t+C)a}-B\right)$$

Now you need to use the given information : when $x=0, t=0$ too.

$$0=\frac{1}{a}\left(e^{(0+C)a}-B\right) \implies e^{aC}=B$$

Now put this back into your equation to get
$$x=\frac{1}{a}\left(e^{aC}\cdot e^{at}-B\right)=\frac{1}{a}\left(B\cdot e^{at}-B\right)$$

And replace$B$ with $bu$, to get

$$x=-\frac{bu}{a}\left(1-e^{at} \right)$$

Comment: Thank you. Mistake seemed to have snowballed.

Comment: Welcome @cylus. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
x = -\frac{b}{a} \frac{e^{at}e^{Ct}}{a}
\end{align}$$

This line isn't correct, it should be:

$$\begin{align}
x = -\frac{b}{a} +\frac{e^{(t+C)a}}{a}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you much appreciated.

Comment: yw @cylus hop it helped you...

Answer (score 0):

It is right up to the third-to-last step, so you did the calculus correctly and slipped up on the algebra (it happens to everyone :D):
$$e^{\ln{|ax+b|}}=e^{(t+C)a}$$
Then you accidentally distributed the wrong letter in the exponent on the RHS, so the next step should be:
$$ax+b=e^{at+Ca}$$
Of course, $e^{Ca}$ is just a constant, so replace it by $c$:
$$ax+b=e^{at+Ca}=e^{at}e^{Ca}=ce^{at}$$
Then, solve for $x$:
$$x=\frac{ce^{at}-b}{a}=\frac{ce^{at}}{a}-\frac{b}{a}$$
To bring it into the required form, first factor out $-\frac{b}{a}$:
$$x=-\frac{b}{a}\left(1-bce^{at}\right)$$
Then replace $b$ back with $bu$:
$$x=-\frac{bu}{a}\left(1-buce^{at}\right)$$
Then use $x(0)=0$ to conclude that $buc=1$, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Was looking at the problem for some time and didn’t see the mistake which ended up snow balling. Thx.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.